# Divide the Android Screen in two equal half

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, latitude-longitude

I have recently started working with Android. I don't have that much experience with Android. This is my first time working with Android. I need to divide the screen in two equal half and then perform few tasks.

1. After dividing the screen in two equal half, In second half (means bottom half) I need to make a Label named `Latitude` then corresponding to that a `Textbox` that will show the current latitude values and another label named `Longitude` and corresponding to that another `Textbox` and that will show current longitude value.

I started working on this, And I made some progress- Below is my XML file that I am using currently to divide the screen in two equal half.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.8"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000" >

        <!-- Latitude Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Latitude"
            android:textColor="#372c24" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true" />
        <!-- Longitude Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Longitude"
            android:textColor="#372c24" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:password="true"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Question is-

1. After using the above XML file, I am not able to see my `both label` and `both textbox` properly on the Android Screen, Is there anything I am missing here in my XML file?
2. Secondly, how I can show the current latitude and longitude value in the corresponding textbox.

Any help will be appreciated as I am new to Android world.

Update:- Below is the diagram that I made in a paint, I want something Like that.[image]

If you look at the screen, it got divided in two parts, and in the bottom half part, there are two Labels (Latitude and Longitude) and it should be like that, and infront of each label, there will be a textbox that will hold the corresponding latitude and longitude values.

**Update Code:-** For Current Location-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    private TextView latituteField;
    private TextView longitudeField;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;

    private static final String TAG = "CurrentLocation";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat1);
        longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat2);

     // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the location provider -> use
        // default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       if (location != null) {
           System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
           int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
           int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
           Log.v(TAG, lat+ " "+ lng);
           latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
           longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
       } else {
           latituteField.setText("Provider not available");
           longitudeField.setText("Provider not available");
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

But the below code is not showing any latitude or longitude values on the corresponding text box? ANything wrong I am doing?

Comment: Oops.. Sorry about that.. I forgot to accept the answer. I did it now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "After using the above XML file, I am not able to see my both label and
>   both textbox properly on the Android Screen, Is there anything I am
>   missing here in my XML file?"

It appeared, you may have had your `LinearLayout` tags messed up.

See if this is closer to what you are looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- currently empty -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <!-- Latitude Label -->

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Latitude"
                android:textColor="#372c24" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="0.35"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="test1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <!-- Longitude Label -->

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Longitude"
                android:textColor="#372c24" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="0.35"
                android:password="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="test2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Picture

[image]

---

> "Secondly, how I can show the current latitude and longitude value in
>   the corresponding textbox."

What have you attempted?

You need to get the current lat/long.
Then just set the text on the `EditText`.

Comment: Thanks prolink for suggestion, but this is not the way I wanted. Currently I am getting Latitude and Longitude at the Top and both the Label are coming infront of each other and I cannot see the corresponding textbox also. And I need both the label and corresponding textbox at the bottom half of the page in second linear layout.

Comment: Can you draw a simple picture of what you are wanting and post it here? That would make understanding this much easier for everyone.

Comment: I changed it to a vertical `LinearLayout`, see if that is what you are talking about.

Comment: I just made another change too, see if that helped.

Comment: I updated my question with the picture that I made in a paint. Hope that will make more clear to you.

Comment: I tried your XML file, but still Latitude lable is going at the top half of the screen but I need something like the picture that I have made.

Comment: Nice pic! Now i see what you are saying. Check out my answer again, let me know what you think.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I need. But somehow Label and its corresponding textbox are very far from each other. And distance between two labels is also very far. Is there any way to control that?

Comment: @Nevzz03 change the weights of the text and edit text view like  android:layout_weight=".8" for text view and  android:layout_weight=".4" for edit text

Comment: I changed the weights a little. You will just have to play with the weights until you get something you like. If you do not prefer the weights method, then you could try a `RelativeLayout` or static sizes for your `Views`.

Comment: Do you want to display long. and lat in text view or edit text